# CSS underline animation - Reading direction

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, underline

I found a code to animate the underline of a link but I would like to be on the other direction, as we read (left to right) which is actually the opposite. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Leshautsdurant/pp21kmms/)

```css
.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:hover:before {
  width: 0%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:hover:after {
  width: 0%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse">
  I want it to slide on the other direction.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value declaration of left and right.

i.e. `.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:before` consist of `left:0` change that to `right:0` and same in other `pseudo selector :after` `right:0` to `left:0`. This changes the direction and makes line to start from `left to right`.

```css
.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:hover:before {
  width: 0%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:hover:after {
  width: 0%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse">
  I want it to slide on the other direction.
</div>
```

Comment: @Leshautsdurant As you added that you found code to animate underline, so I suggest you to change there background to different colors, to understand how it works.

Comment: Welcome @Leshautsdurant :-)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* changed from 'right' */
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:hover:before {
  width: 0%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width .8s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse:hover:after {
  width: 0%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width 0s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliding-u-l-r-l-inverse">
  I want it to slide on the other direction.
</div>
```